# How to install a Chrome Extension not in the Downloads folder in Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

The file picker in Chrome OS only shows the Downloads folder. How can we load an unpacked extension in Chrome that isn't in the Downloads folder?

Comment: I don't know about ChromeOS but maybe you can simply drag'n'drop the extension folder just like in other OS?

Comment: Check https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-dev-editor/pnoffddplpippgcfjdhbmhkofpnaalpg

Comment: https://crbug.com/136349

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a project folder within the download folder and load it from there. I wanted to do the same thing but Chrome OS doesn't seem to be able to create folders outside of the download folder unless it's done in your Google Drive.